# Automatic hyperlink function based on criteria

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have an Excel sheet with a column of a list of invoices, every row in that column lists a different invoice number. On my hard drive I have the actual invoices as PDF files.

I would like the cells in the Excel sheet to be automatically hyperlinked to the invoices which are on my hard drive. All invoices are in this folder: `C:/Invoices`, each invoice has a different number.

So for example when I enter in a cell the invoice number 2556 - I would need Excel to automatically hyperlink that cell to the location `C:/Invoices/2556.pdf`; when I enter invoice number 9987784 - I would need Excel to automatically hyperlink that cell to `C:/Invoices/9987784.pdf` and so on.

I tried doing this with the `IF` and `Hyperlink` functions together, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Anything to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the code piece where you are stuck now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the number in **A1** , in **B1** enter:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\Invoices\" & A1 & ".pdf", A1)
```

Comment: Wow, this was really awesome. I know comments are not made for saying thanks but I can't help it (and my reputation is not enough for upvoting). So sorry but thank you...